# What kind of database should I use for tracking operations for a model railroad?

Tags: c#, database

I'm not sure where to ask this question, so I'll start here. Basically, I was handed a very old program written in a very old language (QB 4.5) and asked to convert it to a modern-ish language. I plan on using C# and I imagine using a database to keep track of inventory as well as car movement, but I'm trying to figure out what kind of database to use? The end goal is to create an exe file that the users will install once and use the GUI to manage their model railroad operations. Should I create something like multiple CSVs/text files or use something more like an Access Database? I can't imagine any one user of the program having millions of records, so I surely don't need and kind of Microsoft SQL or Oracle instance. So here I am, asking for suggestions.

Comment: many applications, including browsers like firefox, use sqlite as a local-only database storage. You can include it as a library and store your database file in the user directory. Should be more than enough to meet your requirements.

Comment: Is that something that still has to be installed separately than the program I am going to end up compiling? I'm looking at the sqlite page and it looks like it could be ultra lightweight, which is good though.

Comment: no installation, just include it as a project reference. Or do one better and install it from nuget, which would make updating easier: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: Ah, now I'm tracking. As a reference, this page is also pretty good for SQLite newbies like me. http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Comment: and if you're a fan of slight overengineering and "because I can", .Net Entity Framework supports sqlite as well.

Comment: Haha, duly noted Dirk!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#, my recommendation is Microsoft SQL Server. You can spin up an instance on Azure for ~$5/month if you don't feel like installing a local instance. Entity Framework can be nice if you don't feel like peppering custom SQL statements in your code base.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your answer. Definitely don't need anything like that though, lol. It is going to be local database instances once the program is installed on a user's computer, not something anyone would connect to in a cloud or anything like that. Thanks though!